# How can I connect to MySQL on Heroku?

Tags: python, mysql, django, heroku

I have a Django project that uses MySQL as its database. On my development machine the MySQL database runs on my local machine as shown here:

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'xxx',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        #'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

I have successfully deployed the project to Heroku, but it keeps showing that

> 2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)

since the setting is the local MySQL and the `views.py` contain functions that import local database. I still cannot figure out how to have the website to connect to this database.

Is there a way to make this work with Heroku, or do I need to find another host?

Comment: "which server is the best choice to deploy online for my case?" That's off-topic on Stack Overflow. It's primarily opinion-based and asks us to find or recommend an off-site resource. However, "how can I make this work on Heroku" is _on-topic_. Please review what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic] and try to frame your questions accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

[juanmhidalgo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52378789/354577) is a good start, and can be generalized for arbitrary environment variables. But if you only care about the database variable there's another solution.

By default, Heroku provides a PostgreSQL database and sets your application's `DATABASE_URL` with a connection string that can be used to connect to it.

As far as I know, the various MySQL addons also set this variable but it would be helpful to know which one you've selected so we can confirm. It may need to be set manually, based on another environment variable.

Assuming that the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable is properly set you can use [`dj-database-url`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url) to set your database up directly, optionally providing a fallback to use when the variable isn't available (e.g. on your development box), in your `settings.py` file:

```
import dj_database_url

DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(
    default='mysql://root:<password>@localhost:3306/<database>',
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After made the change in setting, the deployed web still shows that: 2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)"

Comment: Please run `heroku config` (or look at your app's settings in your dashboard). Do you see a variable whose value looks like a URL starting with `mysql://`? Please _don't_ share that value with us, but what's the name of that variable?

Comment: It's something like this: DATABASE_URL: mysql2://root:xxx@localhost

Comment: That's not going to work. Which MySQL addon are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can promote the settings.py to a package. Create the settings folder like this one

```
settings/
├── __init__.py
├── base.py
├── dev.py
├── heroku.py
```

Keep the base.py as your settings.py and then, based on the env, changes what you need.

Your heroku.py could be

```
from .base import *

DATABASE = {
    # change to use the database on heroku
}
```

What is important is to tell the deploy version to use the new settings. Check the wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

# point to the new settings.dev as default, if the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`
# is not set
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings.dev")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Remember to change the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in heroku to `settings.heroku`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To be specific, the django module with local mysql will save the input information from the web automatically, such as user, datetime, et al. But when I deploy it online, where could I retrieve such information? I may use this information in the next processing steps in view.py functions. Thx!

Comment: can you show an example of how you save the input informations?

Answer (score 1):

A really useful way to do this is to use [django-environ](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ) and set the configuration option on the heroku settings.

```
# settings.py
# Parse database connection url strings like psql://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8458/db
DATABASES = {
    # read os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] and raises ImproperlyConfigured exception if not found
    'default': env.db(),

}
```

and your environment variable like:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://user:%23password@127.0.0.1:3306/dbname
```

Regarding your question, Heroku is a really good option to deploy your projects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry that I have be absent for a while to reply. Do I need to change all the setting in setting.py for django-environ? I googled it, it seems that there are many modification compared with the orignal os system. Thx!